# Uncheck radio buttons on selecting another one - Not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

There are 2 main radio buttons (opt1 and opt2). opt1 has 3 sub radio buttons. What i need to do is when opt1 is selected nothing should happen but when opt2 is selected, the radio buttons named "main_sub" should be unchecked.

I have tried the below code, **it works fine in Firefox and chrome not in IE.**

HTML:

```
<div class="field">
                  <label>Radio button
                 </label>
                  <table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="radio" name="main"  id="main" value="Yes" />
                    Opt1 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td id="show"  style="padding-left:25px; width:200px; padding-top:5px;  line-height:20px;"><input type="radio" name="main_sub" id="main_sub" value=""  />
                        sub Opt1<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="main_sub"  id="main_sub" value=""  />
                        sub Opt2<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="main_sub"  id="main_sub" value=""  />
                        sub Opt2<br>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <table align="center"  width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="padding-right:60px;" ><input type="radio" name="main"  id="main" value="No" />
                        Opt2</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("main2").addEventListener("change", function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        var subs_list = document.getElementsByName("main_sub");
        var subs = Array.prototype.slice.call(subs_list);
        subs.forEach(function(sub){
            sub.checked = false;
        });
    }
});

var subs_list_2 = document.getElementsByName("main_sub");
var subs_2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(subs_list_2);
subs_2.forEach(function(sub){
    sub.addEventListener("change", function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            document.getElementById("main2").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("main").checked = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That may be because you are reusing IDs for several elements, which is illegal. Each element should have a unique ID. Try changing the IDs to `main_sub1` and `main_sub2` or similar.

Comment: it works fine at my IE9

Comment: Passing a host object as *this* to a native function (e.g. `Array.prototype.slice.call(subs_list_2);`) will fail in IE 8 and lower (i.e. browsers that don't support *addEventListener*) so you will need to re-write that part too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure if addEventListener works in IE, for IE, you might wanna use attachEvent. IE11 supports addEventListener so if you're using an older version of IE or any of your users are then use attachEvent..refer to these sites..

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: It makes sense. How to rewrite the JS ? I mean how to replace addEventListener to attachEvent ?

Comment: you could try a check as so on the object you're listening on.ie.

if( obj.addEventListener ) obj.addEventListener(event, function(){}, boolean)
else if( obj.attachEvent ) obj.attachEvent(event, function(){})

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment, using an answer so I can properly format it.

Where you have:

```
    var subs = Array.prototype.slice.call(subs_list);
    subs.forEach(function(sub){
        sub.checked = false;
    });
```

the first line will fail in IE 8 and lower because it will not tolerate host objects being passed to built-in functions as *this*. Also, the above is actually more to type than the more robust alternative loop:

```
for (var i=0, iLen=subs_list.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  subs_list[i].checked = false;
}
```